# Pointer to an object in inheritance

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, inheritance

Here I'm not getting correct output, Here I used inheritance concept, but I don't know, how to call method using object of pointer type.

Please some one give me some solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;    

class person
{
private:
    char *name,*blood,*dob;
    int height,weight;
public:
    static int count;
    person()
    {
        strcpy(name,"Name");
        strcpy(blood,"Blood");
        height=0;
        weight=0;
    }
    ~person()
    {
    }
    friend class person_info;
};


class person_info
{
private:
    char *add,*tel,*lic,*insu;
public:
    void getdata(person *obj,int n);
    void display(person *obj);

};

void person_info::getdata(person *obj,int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter Name Of the Person : ";
        cin.getline(obj->name,30);

        cout<<"Enter Blood group Of the Person : ";
        cin.getline(obj->blood,30);

        cout<<"Enter date of birth of the Person : ";
        cin.getline(obj->dob,30);

        cout<<"Enter Height of the Person : ";
        cin>>obj->height;

        cout<<"Enter Weight of the Person : ";
        cin>>obj->weight;

        cout<<"Enter Address Of the Person : ";
        cin.getline(this->add,30);

        cout<<"Enter Insurance no. Of the Person : ";
        cin.getline(this->insu,30);

        cout<<"Enter Telephone no Of the Person : ";
        cin.getline(this->tel,30);

        cout<<"Enter License no the Person : ";
        cin.getline(obj->blood,30);
    }
}
void person_info::display(person *obj)
{
    cout<<setw[10]<<"Name"<<setw[10]<<"Address"<<setw[10]<<"D. O. B."<<setw[3]<<"Blood G."<<setw[4]<<"Height"<<setw[10]<<"Weight"<<setw[10]<<"Insrn No."<<setw[10]<<"Tele No."<<setw[11]<<"Licence No.";
    cout<<setw[10]<<obj->name<<setw[10]<<this->add<<setw[10]<<obj->dob<<setw[3]<<obj->blood<<setw[4]<<obj->height<<setw[10]<<obj->weight<<setw[10]<<this->insu<<setw[10]<<this->tel<<setw[11]<<this->lic;
}

int main()
{
int ch=0,i=0,n;
    do
    {
        cout<<"1.getdata"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.display data"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter choice";
        cin>>ch;
        person_info *p[2];        \\I think this part is not correct
        p[2]=new person_info();   \\I think this part is not correct
        person *p1[2];            \\I think this part is not correct
        p1[2]=new person();       \\I think this part is not correct
        switch(ch) 
        { 
        case 1: 
            cout<<"Enter No. Entries to be Entered :"; 
            cin>>n; 
            p[2]->getdata(p1[2],n);
            break;
        case 2: 
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                p[i]->display(p1[i]); 
            }
            break;
        }
    }while(ch!=3);
```

Comment: You never allocated memory for `name`, `strcpy(name,"Name");` this calls undefined behavior. Rather use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: `p[2]=new person_info();` accesses one past the end of the array.  this causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You claim to be "using inheritance," but there's no inheritance actually happening in your code. Did you mean for one of your "person" classes to inherit from the other?

Answer (score 3):

You neither initialized your members `char *name,*blood,*dob;`, nor you allocated memory for them. I recommend to use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

```
#include <string>

class person
{
   private:
   std::string name;
   std::string blood;
public:
    person()
        : name( "Name" )
        , blood( "Blood" )
    {}
    person( const char *n, const char *b )
        : name( n )
        , blood( b )
    {}
};
```

Note: `strcpy(name,"Name");` copies the string `"Name"` to the memory referenced by `char *name`, but you never allocate any dynamic memory for `name`. `name` is not initialized and undefined.